# Is it possible to load a child theme from a remote server?

Tags: child-theme

Was wondering if we could store and serve a child theme (style & functions pages) on a remote server or website instead of a folder within the main theme & hosting? Or do you always have to upload and add a child theme through the main wordpress theme dashboard?

Comment: Your main server will need to run the PHP files so it ought to have them locally if possible.  You could e.g. read them from a shared NFS folder though, but I'd avoid it if possible. Styles and other static files could be served by another server, yes.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do here? Keep the child theme up-to-date from outside WordPress somehow, perhaps for multiple servers at once?

Comment: Thanks Rup - yes, the ability to edit and update a theme without having to go through the wordpress dashboard etc. Thanks